# UEFI Secure Boot is not compatible with the use of third-party drivers

Tags: boot, virtualbox, uefi

An ongoing issue with Ubuntu 14.04 where Virtualbox wouldn't run on the 3.13.0-92 kernel appears to have maybe been fixed in the newest update to 3.13.0-93.  However, after the GUI update failing (locking up) and doing a command-line update instead, there were some dialogue boxes, one of which asked for a password.  However, I rebooted and did not press a key in time before the "Press any key to perform MOK management" dialogue disappeared.  Now it seems impossible to get back to this.  How do I continue the update process?  I reran the updater and this has not come back.  I was told I'd need to put the same password into the MOK management dialogue upon reboot but not told I'd have to press a key to get to it within a couple seconds, and that there would only be one chance to do this...

How do I get back to the MOK management dialouge so I can enable the virtualbox kernel module?

Comment: VirtualBox suggests running "sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup" which only works on kernel 3.13.0-91 and prior.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get "Required key not available" when install 3rd party kernel modules or after a kernel upgrade?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules)

Comment: Disabling Secure Boot in BIOS did make VirtualBox work on the newer Linux, but the question was specifically "How do I get back to the MOK management dialouge ... ?"

Comment: There is an answer. You could enable validation by `mokutil` and re-install `vitrualbox` or re-configure it.